# constantLine function not working in graphite (0.9.12) and django 1.6.1

Tags: python, django, json, apache, graphite

I am currently using graphite 0.9.12 with django 1.6.1 , I am able to acquire the stored metrics both is json and image formats. However when i try the constantLine function in json  format, i get the following error:

I am unable to figure out why this is happening, I am running my graphite and statsd on 64 bit ubuntu 12.04 VM. I am being suspicious about wsgi, I installed libapache2-mod-wsgi and pointed my wsgi in config to /var/run/apache2/wsgi. What could error have been? and how do we rectify it

```
TypeError at /render
range() integer end argument expected, got float.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://10.0.1.11/render?target=stats.gauges.server1.throughput&target=threshold(400,%22redboy%22)&from=-2mins&format=json
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
range() integer end argument expected, got float.
Exception Location: /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/views.py in renderView, line 132
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/opt/graphite/webapp',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/opt/graphite/webapp',
 '/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/thirdparty']
Server time:    Wed, 18 Dec 2013 15:16:44 +0530
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
e   
TypeError('range() integer end argument expected, got float.',)
callback_args   
()
resolver_match  
ResolverMatch(func=<function renderView at 0x7fee2428eb18>, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name='graphite.render.views.renderView', app_name='None', namespace='')
middleware_method   
<bound method MessageMiddleware.process_request of <django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware object at 0x7fee353d7e50>>
self    
<django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x7fee2c9b8ed0>
request 
'<WSGIRequest\npath:/render,\nGET:<QueryDict: {u\'from\': [u\'-2mins\'], u\'target\': [u\'stats.gauges.server1.throughput\', u\'threshold(400,"redboy")\'], u\'format\': [u\'json\']}>,\nPOST:<QueryDict: {}>,\nCOOKIES:{},\nMETA:{\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\': \'/opt/graphite/webapp\',\n \'GATEWAY_INTERFACE\': \'CGI/1.1\',\n \'HTTP_ACCEPT\': \'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\',\n \'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING\': \'gzip,deflate,sdch\',\n \'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE\': \'en-US,en;q=0.8\',\n \'HTTP_CONNECTION\': \'keep-alive\',\n \'HTTP_HOST\': \'10.0.1.11\',\n \'HTTP_USER_AGENT\': \'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.114 Safari/537.36\',\n \'PATH_INFO\': u\'/render\',\n \'PATH_TRANSLATED\': \'/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi/render\',\n \'QUERY_STRING\': \'target=stats.gauges.server1.throughput&target=threshold(400,%22redboy%22)&from=-2mins&format=json\',\n \'REMOTE_ADDR\': \'10.0.1.1\',\n \'REMOTE_PORT\': \'53684\',\n \'REQUEST_METHOD\': \'GET\',\n \'REQUEST_URI\': \'/render?target=stats.gauges.server1.throughput&target=threshold(400,%22redboy%22)&from=-2mins&format=json\',\n \'SCRIPT_FILENAME\': \'/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi\',\n \'SCRIPT_NAME\': u\'\',\n \'SERVER_ADDR\': \'10.0.1.11\',\n \'SERVER_ADMIN\': \'[no address given]\',\n \'SERVER_NAME\': \'10.0.1.11\',\n \'SERVER_PORT\': \'80\',\n \'SERVER_PROTOCOL\': \'HTTP/1.1\',\n \'SERVER_SIGNATURE\': \'<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.0.1.11 Port 80</address>\\n\',\n \'SERVER_SOFTWARE\': \'Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)\',\n \'mod_wsgi.application_group\': \'\',\n \'mod_wsgi.callable_object\': \'application\',\n \'mod_wsgi.handler_script\': \'\',\n \'mod_wsgi.input_chunked\': \'0\',\n \'mod_wsgi.listener_host\': \'\',\n \'mod_wsgi.listener_port\': \'80\',\n \'mod_wsgi.process_group\': \'graphite\',\n \'mod_wsgi.request_handler\': \'wsgi-script\',\n \'mod_wsgi.script_reloading\': \'1\',\n \'mod_wsgi.version\': (3, 3),\n \'wsgi.errors\': <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7fee24287b70>,\n \'wsgi.file_wrapper\': <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0x7fee348c66c0>,\n \'wsgi.input\': <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7fee24287970>,\n \'wsgi.multiprocess\': True,\n \'wsgi.multithread\': True,\n \'wsgi.run_once\': False,\n \'wsgi.url_scheme\': \'http\',\n \'wsgi.version\': (1, 1)}>'
callback    
<function renderView at 0x7fee2428eb18>
wrapped_callback    
<function renderView at 0x7fee2428eb18>
resolver    
<RegexURLResolver 'graphite.urls' (None:None) ^/>
callback_kwargs 
{}
response    
None
urlconf 
'graphite.urls'
/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/views.py in renderView
        timestamps = range(series.start, series.end, series.step) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
requestKey  
'1bba7830bb12250e806f3cee777f376b'
series  
TimeSeries(name=redboy, start=1387359884.0, end=1387360004.0, step=120.0)
datapoints  
[(1190.0, 1387359890),
 (1190.0, 1387359900),
 (1190.0, 1387359910),
 (1190.0, 1387359920),
 (1190.0, 1387359930),
 (1190.0, 1387359940),
 (1190.0, 1387359950),
 (1190.0, 1387359960),
 (1190.0, 1387359970),
 (1190.0, 1387359980),
 (1190.0, 1387359990),
 (None, 1387360000)]
series_data 
[{'datapoints': [(1190.0, 1387359890),
                 (1190.0, 1387359900),
                 (1190.0, 1387359910),
                 (1190.0, 1387359920),
                 (1190.0, 1387359930),
                 (1190.0, 1387359940),
                 (1190.0, 1387359950),
                 (1190.0, 1387359960),
                 (1190.0, 1387359970),
                 (1190.0, 1387359980),
                 (1190.0, 1387359990),
                 (None, 1387360000)],
  'target': 'stats.gauges.server1.throughput'}]
targets 
[u'stats.gauges.server1.throughput', u'threshold(400,"redboy")']
start   
1387360004.768559
useCache    
True
seriesList  
[TimeSeries(name=redboy, start=1387359884.0, end=1387360004.0, step=120.0)]
dataKey 
'2308e1f7d9425fcc3509081750ec5b6b'
graphOptions    
{'height': 250, 'width': 330}
format  
u'json'
cachedResponse  
None
cacheTimeout    
60
cachedData  
None
startTime   
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 18, 15, 14, 44, 768961, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' IST+5:30:00 STD>)
timestamps  
[1387359890,
 1387359900,
 1387359910,
 1387359920,
 1387359930,
 1387359940,
 1387359950,
 1387359960,
 1387359970,
 1387359980,
 1387359990,
 1387360000]
data    
[TimeSeries(name=stats.gauges.server1.throughput, start=1387359890, end=1387360010, step=10),
 TimeSeries(name=redboy, start=1387359884.0, end=1387360004.0, step=120.0)]
target  
u'threshold(400,"redboy")'
requestContext  
{'data': [TimeSeries(name=stats.gauges.server1.throughput, start=1387359890, end=1387360010, step=10),
          TimeSeries(name=redboy, start=1387359884.0, end=1387360004.0, step=120.0)],
 'endTime': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 18, 15, 16, 44, 768819, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' IST+5:30:00 STD>),
 'localOnly': False,
 'startTime': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 18, 15, 14, 44, 768961, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' IST+5:30:00 STD>)}
request 
'<WSGIRequest\npath:/render,\nGET:<QueryDict: {u\'from\': [u\'-2mins\'], u\'target\': [u\'stats.gauges.server1.throughput\', u\'threshold(400,"redboy")\'], u\'format\': [u\'json\']}>,\nPOST:<QueryDict: {}>,\nCOOKIES:{},\nMETA:{\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\': \'/opt/graphite/webapp\',\n \'GATEWAY_INTERFACE\': \'CGI/1.1\',\n \'HTTP_ACCEPT\': \'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\',\n \'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING\': \'gzip,deflate,sdch\',\n \'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE\': \'en-US,en;q=0.8\',\n \'HTTP_CONNECTION\': \'keep-alive\',\n \'HTTP_HOST\': \'10.0.1.11\',\n \'HTTP_USER_AGENT\': \'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.114 Safari/537.36\',\n \'PATH_INFO\': u\'/render\',\n \'PATH_TRANSLATED\': \'/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi/render\',\n \'QUERY_STRING\': \'target=stats.gauges.server1.throughput&target=threshold(400,%22redboy%22)&from=-2mins&format=json\',\n \'REMOTE_ADDR\': \'10.0.1.1\',\n \'REMOTE_PORT\': \'53684\',\n \'REQUEST_METHOD\': \'GET\',\n \'REQUEST_URI\': \'/render?target=stats.gauges.server1.throughput&target=threshold(400,%22redboy%22)&from=-2mins&format=json\',\n \'SCRIPT_FILENAME\': \'/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi\',\n \'SCRIPT_NAME\': u\'\',\n \'SERVER_ADDR\': \'10.0.1.11\',\n \'SERVER_ADMIN\': \'[no address given]\',\n \'SERVER_NAME\': \'10.0.1.11\',\n \'SERVER_PORT\': \'80\',\n \'SERVER_PROTOCOL\': \'HTTP/1.1\',\n \'SERVER_SIGNATURE\': \'<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.0.1.11 Port 80</address>\\n\',\n \'SERVER_SOFTWARE\': \'Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)\',\n \'mod_wsgi.application_group\': \'\',\n \'mod_wsgi.callable_object\': \'application\',\n \'mod_wsgi.handler_script\': \'\',\n \'mod_wsgi.input_chunked\': \'0\',\n \'mod_wsgi.listener_host\': \'\',\n \'mod_wsgi.listener_port\': \'80\',\n \'mod_wsgi.process_group\': \'graphite\',\n \'mod_wsgi.request_handler\': \'wsgi-script\',\n \'mod_wsgi.script_reloading\': \'1\',\n \'mod_wsgi.version\': (3, 3),\n \'wsgi.errors\': <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7fee24287b70>,\n \'wsgi.file_wrapper\': <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0x7fee348c66c0>,\n \'wsgi.input\': <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7fee24287970>,\n \'wsgi.multiprocess\': True,\n \'wsgi.multithread\': True,\n \'wsgi.run_once\': False,\n \'wsgi.url_scheme\': \'http\',\n \'wsgi.version\': (1, 1)}>'
t   
1387360004.770751
endTime 
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 18, 15, 16, 44, 768819, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' IST+5:30:00 STD>)
requestOptions  
{'cacheTimeout': 60,
 'endTime': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 18, 15, 16, 44, 768819, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' IST+5:30:00 STD>),
 'format': u'json',
 'graphClass': <class graphite.render.glyph.LineGraph at 0x7fee242829a8>,
 'graphType': 'line',
 'localOnly': False,
 'pieMode': 'average',
 'startTime': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 18, 15, 14, 44, 768961, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' IST+5:30:00 STD>),
 'targets': [u'stats.gauges.server1.throughput', u'threshold(400,"redboy")'],
 'tzinfo': <DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' HMT+5:53:00 STD>}
Request information

GET
Variable    Value
from    
u'-2mins'
target  
u'threshold(400,"redboy")'
format  
u'json'
POST
No POST data
FILES
No FILES data
COOKIES
No cookie data
META
Variable    Value
mod_wsgi.listener_port  
'80'
mod_wsgi.listener_host  
''
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)'
SCRIPT_NAME 
u''
mod_wsgi.handler_script 
''
SERVER_SIGNATURE    
'<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.0.1.11 Port 80</address>\n'
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
PATH_INFO   
u'/render'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
QUERY_STRING    
'target=stats.gauges.server1.throughput&target=threshold(400,%22redboy%22)&from=-2mins&format=json'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.114 Safari/537.36'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
SERVER_NAME 
'10.0.1.11'
REMOTE_ADDR 
'10.0.1.1'
mod_wsgi.request_handler    
'wsgi-script'
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
PATH_TRANSLATED 
'/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi/render'
SERVER_PORT 
'80'
wsgi.multiprocess   
True
mod_wsgi.input_chunked  
'0'
SERVER_ADDR 
'10.0.1.11'
DOCUMENT_ROOT   
'/opt/graphite/webapp'
mod_wsgi.process_group  
'graphite'
SCRIPT_FILENAME 
'/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi'
SERVER_ADMIN    
'[no address given]'
wsgi.input  
<mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7fee24287970>
HTTP_HOST   
'10.0.1.11'
wsgi.multithread    
True
mod_wsgi.callable_object    
'application'
REQUEST_URI 
'/render?target=stats.gauges.server1.throughput&target=threshold(400,%22redboy%22)&from=-2mins&format=json'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
wsgi.version    
(1, 1)
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.errors 
<mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7fee24287b70>
REMOTE_PORT 
'53684'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-US,en;q=0.8'
mod_wsgi.version    
(3, 3)
mod_wsgi.application_group  
''
mod_wsgi.script_reloading   
'1'
wsgi.file_wrapper   
''
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip,deflate,sdch'
Settings
Using settings module graphite.settings
Setting Value
REMOTE_RENDERING    
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
TIME_ZONE   
'Asia/Calcutta'
DOCUMENTATION_URL   
'http://graphite.readthedocs.org/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
LDAP_URI    
None
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
ROOT_URLCONF    
'graphite.urls'
MANAGERS    
()
CARBONLINK_TIMEOUT  
1.0
GRAPHITE_ROOT   
'/opt/graphite'
CLUSTER_SERVERS 
[]
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
WEBAPP_DIR  
'/opt/graphite/webapp'
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
STATIC_ROOT 
''
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
['*']
REMOTE_RENDER_CONNECT_TIMEOUT   
1.0
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
DATABASE_HOST   
''
WSGI_APPLICATION    
None
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS 
False
CONF_DIR    
'/opt/graphite/conf'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
LDAP_BASE_USER  
''
ADMIN_FOR   
()
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M')
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': '/opt/graphite/storage/graphite.db',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': u'********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST_CHARSET': None,
             'TEST_COLLATION': None,
             'TEST_MIRROR': None,
             'TEST_NAME': None,
             'TIME_ZONE': 'Asia/Calcutta',
             'USER': ''}}
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
('django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler')
LOG_CACHE_PERFORMANCE   
False
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/html'
REMOTE_STORE_RETRY_DELAY    
60
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
APPEND_SLASH    
False
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
CARBONLINK_HOSTS    
['127.0.0.1:7002']
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
INDEX_FILE  
'/opt/graphite/storage/index'
CSS_DIR 
'/opt/graphite/webapp/content/css'
LEGEND_MAX_ITEMS    
10
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
USE_I18N    
True
LDAP_USER_QUERY 
''
SECRET_KEY  
u'********************'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
USE_REMOTE_USER_AUTHENTICATION  
False
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
LDAP_SEARCH_BASE    
''
TRANSACTIONS_MANAGED    
False
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'django.utils.log.dictConfig'
TEMPLATE_LOADERS    
('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')
LOG_DIR 
'/opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp'
REMOTE_STORE_FIND_TIMEOUT   
2.5
TEMPLATE_DEBUG  
False
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'SAMEORIGIN'
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
u'********************'
CACHE_BACKEND   
'dummy:///'
LDAP_PORT   
389
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
REMOTE_STORE_FETCH_TIMEOUT  
6
LDAP_BASE_PASS  
u'********************'
JAVASCRIPT_DEBUG    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
FILE_CHARSET    
'utf-8'
DEBUG   
True
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
INSTALLED_APPS  
('graphite.metrics',
 'graphite.render',
 'graphite.cli',
 'graphite.browser',
 'graphite.composer',
 'graphite.account',
 'graphite.dashboard',
 'graphite.whitelist',
 'graphite.events',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'tagging')
LANGUAGES   
(('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy-nl', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmal'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-cn', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-tw', 'Traditional Chinese'))
USE_L10N    
False
DATABASE_ENGINE 
''
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
DATABASE_NAME   
''
PREPEND_WWW 
False
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
DATABASE_PORT   
''
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
LOGIN_URL   
'/account/login'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
LDAP_SERVER 
''
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
MEMCACHE_HOSTS  
[]
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y')
GRAPHITE_WEB_APP_SETTINGS_LOADED    
True
CONTENT_DIR 
'/opt/graphite/webapp/content'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
u'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
REMOTE_FIND_CACHE_DURATION  
300
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX  
'/media/'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
FLUSHRRDCACHED  
''
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
()
LOCALE_PATHS    
()
WHITELIST_FILE  
'/opt/graphite/storage/lists/whitelist'
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID  
''
COMMENTS_ALLOW_PROFANITIES  
False
LOGOUT_URL  
'/accounts/logout/'
STORAGE_DIR 
'/opt/graphite/storage'
DASHBOARD_CONF  
'/opt/graphite/conf/dashboard.conf'
RRD_DIR 
'/opt/graphite/storage/rrd/'
FIXTURE_DIRS    
()
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
MEDIA_ROOT  
''
THIRDPARTY_DIR  
'/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/thirdparty'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
ADMINS  
()
LOG_METRIC_ACCESS   
False
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
WEB_DIR 
'/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite'
STATICFILES_DIRS    
()
MEDIA_URL   
''
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
TEMPLATE_DIRS   
('/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/templates',)
DATA_DIRS   
['/opt/graphite/storage/whisper/']
SITE_ID 
1
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
()
ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS   
()
USE_LDAP_AUTH   
False
LOGGING 
{}
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
DATABASE_USER   
''
WEBAPP_VERSION  
'0.9.12'
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder')
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
u'********************'
SMTP_SERVER 
'localhost'
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
WHISPER_DIR 
'/opt/graphite/storage/whisper/'
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS 
('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
 'django.core.context_processors.debug',
 'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
 'django.core.context_processors.media',
 'django.core.context_processors.static',
 'django.core.context_processors.tz',
 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages')
RENDERING_HOSTS 
[]
ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_CLI 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'graphite.settings'
USE_ETAGS   
False
DEFAULT_CACHE_DURATION  
60
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
('he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur')
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
INTERNAL_IPS    
()
STATIC_URL  
None
EMAIL_PORT  
25
LOG_RENDERING_PERFORMANCE   
False
USE_TZ  
False
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
u'********************'
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y')
DATABASE_PASSWORD   
u'********************'
GRAPHTEMPLATES_CONF 
'/opt/graphite/conf/graphTemplates.conf'
DJANGO_VERSION  
(1, 6, 1, 'final', 0)
PROFANITIES_LIST    
u'********************'
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 500 page.
```

****UPDATE:
I have applied the fix suggested to typecast to integers: Now i receive only a single value.

Now the following url `[http://10.0.1.11/render?target=stats.gauges.server1.throughput&target=threshold(400,%22redboy%22)&from=-1mins&format=json]` returns:

```
[{"target": "stats.gauges.server1.throughput", "datapoints": [[1190.0, 1387362760], [1190.0, 1387362770], [1190.0, 1387362780], [1190.0, 1387362790], [1190.0, 1387362800], [null, 1387362810]]}, {"target": "redboy", "datapoints": [[400, 1387362755]]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by casting `range` params to int, in render/views.py:

```
timestamps = range(int(series.start), int(series.end), int(series.step))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer: Now I donot get an error but, i get only a single value ; [{"target": "stats.gauges.server1.throughput", "datapoints": [[1190.0, 1387362760], [1190.0, 1387362770], [1190.0, 1387362780], [1190.0, 1387362790], [1190.0, 1387362800], [null, 1387362810]]}, {"target": "redboy", "datapoints": [[400, 1387362755]]}]

Answer (score 0):

Maby use:

> timestamps = range(int(series.start), int(series.end)**+1**,
>   int(series.step))

Range dont take the last value. => constantline has 1 metric :(